# How do I escape double backslashes for MathJax?

Tags: html, wordpress, markdown, mathjax, backslash

I make MathJax work with WordPress by adding the following code to `footer.php`. It works for simple math symbols and equations.

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Config({
    tex2jax: {
        inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],
            processEscapes: true
    }
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>
```

But it doesn't work for the equations with multiline, such as,

[image]

It is rendered as one line as shown below.

[image]

This is caused by rendering `\\` as `\` by default in WordPress or markdown editor. One possible solution is to turn all `\\` within `$$...$$` into `\\\\`.

I expect I can use `\\` as a line break directly. It works on [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io/), but I don't know how, probably escaping `\\` for MathJax.

---

Here is the source code. (I use markdown editor.)

```
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
PR(p_1) \\
PR(p_2) \\
\vdots \\
PR(p_N)
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
{(1-d)/ N} \\
{(1-d) / N} \\
\vdots \\
{(1-d) / N}
\end{bmatrix}
+ d
\begin{bmatrix}
\ell(p_1,p_1) & \ell(p_1,p_2) & \cdots & \ell(p_1,p_N) \\
\ell(p_2,p_1) & \ddots &  & \vdots \\
\vdots & & \ell(p_i,p_j) & \\
\ell(p_N,p_1) & \cdots & & \ell(p_N,p_N)
\end{bmatrix} 
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
PR(p_1) \\
PR(p_2) \\
\vdots \\
PR(p_N)
\end{bmatrix}
$$
```

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\` is an escape character commonly used across many programming languages.

Example: In C languages `\n` indicates a line break. Here the `n` is indicating a new line and the `\` is telling the compiler to look at the `n` differently then a normal `n`. The escape character `\` is used to tell the compiler that the character directly following it is not normal and should be treated differently (as a `\n` newline character for example).

You could use a `\` before every actual `\` you want to use. So if you wanted `\begin{bmatrix}` you would have to write `\\begin{bmatrix}` and if you want `\\` you need to use `\\\\`.

It is also possible to mark text as 'verbatim' text in some systems. This way you can mark a whole block of text to ignore all characters that would otherwise have a special meaning in the programming language. This is different from system to system, Markdown uses `` `code block` `` or ``` ``code block`` ```.

Try marking your math as a code block and you should be able to use backslashes normally e.g. `` `math here` ``.

Detailed explanation:
http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#tex-and-latex-in-html-documents

Comment: Thx. I mentioned your solution in my question. I am seeking a solution that I can use double backslashes `\\` directly.

Comment: I added a link to the detailed explanation in my answer. Read through the whole section, it covers pretty much everything.

Comment: Also edited it to incorporate another way of doing it.