# 'react-native-mathjax' not rendering for single backslash

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mathjax

I am using 'react-native-mathjax' to render math equations. 'react-native-mathjax' not able to render for single backslash. When I add double backslash in place of single backslash and four backslashes in place of double backslash in the equation given below, 'react-native-mathjax' renders the equation, is there any solution?

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
    import MathJax from 'react-native-mathjax';

    function Test() {
            return (
                   <View>
                     <MathJax
                        html={<p><span class="math-tex">\(\begin{bmatrix} 2 &1 \\[0.3em] 3&4\\[0.3em] \end{bmatrix}\)</span></p>} // not rendering this eqation  
                  />
                   </View>
     );
    }
    export default Test;
```

Comment: if you check the docs, this is meant for use in Webview, to render html. Hence you are not experiencing the correct behavior.

Comment: the thing is it's generated in html, while you can only use html in webview in react native. so you need to use <WebView>

Comment: yes. are u generating it in webview? In the code provided u r using view.

Comment: sorry I just saw that. because \ is a special escaping character, I doubt u can't use single slash. \\ is converted to '\' and this applies across many system.

Comment: good explanation here -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/42292020/2822041

Comment: next time ask question properly. so u want to know how to replace a / in a string to //? is that what u are asking?

Comment: do it by hand, if the string come from database, do the replacement on backend.

Comment: I was testing with local data. but when I received data from an API it's rendering all data. My problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using custom html data in `react-native-mathjax` which requires double backslash in place of single backslash and four backslashes in place of double backslash to render mathematical equations correctly.
When data will come from API it will automatically contain a double backslash in place of single backslash and four backslashes in place of double backslash. So you don't have to do anything new in `react-native-mathjax`.

Comment: It's true. Thanks.